# Xamarin error ios Simulator HE0046: Failed to install the app ... Failed to install the requested application

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, ios-simulator

I changed name of my VS 2019 project running on Mac (from PrismApp1 to something else) and now I can't run on iOS simulator. Tried to run on different simulator phone too.  I searched for PrismApp1 in folder and on machine can't find anything... delete bin and obj folders and did a Build All. any ideas?

error HE0046: Failed to install the app 'com.companyname.PrismApp1' on the device 'iOS 13.2 (17B102) - iPhone 11 Pro': Failed to install the requested application

Note: it works if i deploy to my physical iPhone...

Comment: Does it work when you rename it back? Try to rename the project within VS. Or else you would have to create a new project with that name and just move over the files

Comment: Is the new name contains  an "_" (underscore) as mentioned [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/591502/error-he0046-failed-to-install-the-app-xxx.html)? Did you tried reset/reoprn the simulator? And which version of Visual studio 2019 are you using?

Comment: no it didn't have a _ .  I was using latest version of 2019 on mac.  anyway i just gave up and created a new ios project so i could get on with my life, and it works now.

Comment: Ok, that's a workaround and anyway it works:).

Comment: I had the same issue. Project was renamed, but not in iOS. I just changed then application name in the info.plist file to match what I had in the android version and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue with iPhone 13 emulator and iOS 15, where I couldn't deploy my app on the simulator, but it worked on a real device.
The error I was getting was:

> error HE0046: Failed to install the app 'ma.myapp.app' on the device 'iOS 15.0 (19A339) - iPhone 13 mini': “Myapp” Needs To Be Updated

This [is how I solved the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69897503/7442601).

Answer (score 0):

I had this weird error after app was successfully compiled and it was simply due to a null variable involved in a plist command executed post build.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to close and reopen VS, it worked for me.