# Can't deploy my Xamarin app to iPhone 13 with iOS 15 Simulator

Tags: xamarin.ios, ios15

I've updated to xcode 13 and Visualstudio for mac to version 8.10.12. And now I have the iphone 13 simulator, with iOS 15. The problem is that when I try to debug my app, I get this error from visual studio.

> error HE0046: Failed to install the app 'ma.myapp.app' on the device 'iOS 15.0 (19A339) - iPhone 13 mini': “Myapp” Needs To Be Updated

In the info.plist, the minimum version is set to iOS 9
And I don't understand why my app runs perfectly on iOS 14 but not on 15. Please can someone help ?

Comment: This link(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59325479/xamarin-error-ios-simulator-he0046-failed-to-install-the-app-failed-to-inst) may hlep you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When I had this error, the error message specified by visualstudio wasn't explicit enough.

So I opened a terminal on my mac and entered the following command

> grep ma.myapp.app ~/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator/ -R

This gave me logs corresponding to the app I tried to deploy.
Once I had these logs, I read the logs corresponding to the time at which the error occurred. And I found out that the error was deeper that expected. Here is the message I got from the logs:

> Failed to find matching arch for input file: ../../~/myapp.NotificationServiceExtension

It turned out that my notification service extension was targeting the wrong architecture.

- I Opened the iOS Build menu in the notification extension project's options or properties menu
- I changed the architecture to target x86_64
- I rebuild and deployed.
  And everything worked well.

Answer (score 2):

After I checked all my project settings and build configurations as the other answers mention I was still getting this error.

Performing a `Simulator` > `Device` > `Erase All Content and Settings...` finally worked for me.

Note this will delete any persisted data an

Comment: This worked for my Uno app. I wonder how the same could be done for macOS?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and discovered I had the wrong configuration selected, one named "Debug" instead of the correct one called "Debug | iPhoneSimulator".

Once I changed the configuration to the correct one the app installed and ran fine on the simulator.

Looking more closely at the issue I saw that the "Debug" config was expecting to be installed on a real device, which explains the architecture error.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.
I think the error is in the command line tool related to simulators.

On your Mac,
Quit all simulators
Go to Xcode

Settings > Locations > Command Line Tools

Click the small arrow button and select your working Xcode app.